# Unix to verify file has no content and empty lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, cut

How to verify that a file has absolutely no content. [ -s $file ] gives if file is zero bytes but how to know if file is absolutely empty with no data that including empty lines ?

```
$cat sample.text

$ ls -lrt sample.text
-rw-r--r-- 1 testuser userstest 1 Jul 31 16:38 sample.text
```

`When i "vi" the file the bottom has this - "sample.text" 1L, 1C`

Comment: can you give an example a file with 0 byte, but with content (including empty lines) in it?

Comment: remove empty lines and do what you tried. alternatively, find the number of characters --wc -c?

Comment: ah! so it was 0 bytes **and** no empty lines. sweet!

Comment: A file with 0 bytes size couldn't possibly contain empty lines. An empty line consists of exactly one character: a line-feed. A file containing at least one empty line must thus be at least 1 byte in size. That is what @Kent was hinting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file might have new line character only.

Try this check:

```
[[ $(tr -d "\r\n" < file|wc -c) -eq 0 ]] && echo "File has no content"
```

Answer (score 2):

A file of 0 size by definition has nothing in it, so you are good to go. However, you probably want to use:

```
if [ \! -s f ]; then echo "0 Sized and completely empty"; fi
```

Have fun!

Comment: Do u mean `f` as the file name? BTW, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Blank lines add data to the file and will therefore increase the file size, which means that just checking whether the file is 0 bytes is sufficient.

For a single file, the methods using the bash built-in `-s` (for `test`, `[` or `[[`). (`[[` makes dealing with `!` less horrible, but is bash-specific)

```
fn="file"
if [[ -f "$fn" && ! -s "$fn" ]]; then # -f is needed since -s will return false on missing files as well
    echo "File '$fn' is empty"
fi
```

A (more) POSIX shell compatible way: (The escaping of exclamation marks can be shell dependant)

```
fn="file"
if test -f "$fn" && test \! -s "$fn"; then
    echo "File '$fn' is empty"
fi
```

For multiple files, find is a better method.

For a single file you can do: (It will print the filename if empty)

```
find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file' -size 0 -print
```

for multiple files, matching the glob `glob*`:(It will print the filenames if empty)

```
find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'glob*' -size 0 -print
```

To allow subdirectories:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name 'glob*' -size 0 -print
```

Some `find` implementations does not require a directory as the first parameter (some do, like the Solaris one). On most implementations, the `-print` parameter can be omitted, if it is not specified, `find` defaults to printing matching files.